# Run c++ windows form in chrome native client

Tags: c++, visual-c++, google-nativeclient

I have a simple c++ windows form in visual studio 2010. I want to know if is possible to have this form working with chrome native client PNaCl.

Comment: Could your provide more details, especially on which libraries your application uses?

Comment: Basically what is used to build a form:
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

Comment: As @bbudge answered, that won't work because it's very Windows specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Native Client plugins work on the Web Platform, which is inherently platform independent. That means no Windows, OS/X or other platform APIs are exposed.

You must either port your app to use HTML / CSS / Javascript + Native Client, or use Native Messaging to allow your web app to communicate with a Native App that contains your Windows Form.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging